# How does ransack take the union of two sets of parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

How does ransack take the union of two sets of parameters

```
    q0 = {:field01_in=>[], :field02_in=>[], :fie4d03_in=>[value01,value02], :field02_in=
>[]}
    q1 = {:field01_in=>[], :field02_in=>[], :fie4d03_in=>[value03,value04], :field02_in=
>[value05]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ransack` support grouping queries by adding a combinator `m: or` (`m: and`) to the query hash. (default combinator is `and`)

so if you want `ransack` take the union of two sets of parameters (i assume that you want to merge 2 results of query `and` of all q0 parameters and query `and` of all q1 parameters)

```rb
q0 = {:field01_in=>[], :field02_in=>[], :fie4d03_in=>[value01,value02], :field02_in=
>[]}
q1 = {:field01_in=>[], :field02_in=>[], :fie4d03_in=>[value03,value04], :field02_in=
>[value05]}

union_params = {groupings: [q0, q1], m: 'or'}
@q = Issue.ransack(union_params)
@issues = @q.result
```